# I cannot install the arch module. I use windows 10 and my development environment is JupyterNotebook. I have tried multiple ways/workarounds

Tags: python, anaconda

I've tried all below

`pip install arch` and `conda install arch`, which gives me below errors respectively

pip install error:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BE9EAFDD30>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/arch/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BE9E9AF490>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/arch/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BE9D796550>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/arch/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BE9F74EE80>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/arch/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BE9F74ED60>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/arch/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for arch
```

conda install error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - arch

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I've also tried below methods which provide similar errors to above:

```
pip install arch -U --no-cache-dir
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" arch-py
conda install -c conda-forge arch-py
pip install arch --install-option="--no-binary"
```

At this point I'm out of ideas.

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge arch-py` also gives you `The following packages are not available from current channels:`? the `pip` error is a netwokring problem. Do you need to configure a proxy on your network?

Comment: as an update, I tried: # pip install --no-binary :all: arch. this seemed to install the module. but now when i import arch, i get the following error: ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject